# Trying to remove commented lines from code with no luck

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, regex, sed

Trying to remove all commented lines from code with sed:

**1) `/* ... */` and `/* \n \n \n */`**

Tried using this structure to hide showing what is inside

```
sed -n '/^\/\*/,/\*\//!p'
```

But it appears to hide what is between different lines and omits the inline `/* .... */`

I mean it works here:

```
/******** 
This readme is intented ...
......
....
....
************/
```

But it doesn't work inline here:

```
/* Just a small bug */
```

It takes the first found `/*` and goes on further searching for `*/` on the next lines:

```
/* Just a small bug */
code
code
code
/*****
To sum up this shows us...
...
...
...
...
******/
```

SO ALL THE CODE UNDER "/* Just a small bug */" is being hidden :(
and i heavily miss this:

```
code
code
code
```

**2) // inline: exluding http:// & https:// before, and including if after**

I'm trying to remove also strings & parts of strings which contain `//` with:

```
sed 's/\/\/.*//'
```

which succeeds only in this implementation when `//` is at the beginning of the line:

```
sed 's/^\/\/.*//'
```

but eventually it removes inline links like `http://` and `https://`

```
code
code https://www.sample.com/abc     // include this URL
code https://www.sample.com/abc     // exclude this URL but leave alow https://anothersample.com/xyz
code
```

Tried searching for sed patterns that search for `http://` and `https://`, ignores them, then search inline for `//` and deletes everything after it (ignoring http/https if they are located after `//`) but with no luck :(

Maybe anyone has a nice idea, would be awesome, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5):

I've created this small text file

```
/* one line comment */

some
multiple
code
here

/*****
multiple
line
comment
*****/

some code http://somelink
some code // some one line comment
```

For this small test file, this command works for removing all comments you mentioned

```
cat comments.txt | sed -n '/^\/\*.*\*\//!p' | sed -n '/ \/\/.*/!p' | sed 's|/\*|\n&|g;s|*/|&\n|g' | sed '/\/\*/,/*\//d'
```

This command is doing this:

1. `sed -n '/^\/\*.*\*\//!p'`: Removes all one line comments like `/* one line comment */` from the test file
2. `sed -n '/ \/\/.*/!p'`: Removes all one line comments like `// some one line comment`, but keep `http://` links. This can be done because of the white space in this part `/ \/\/`. I think, you can change this in `/\s\/\/`
3. `sed 's|/\*|\n&|g;s|*/|&\n|g' | sed '/\/\*/,/*\//d'`: Remove all multiple comment lines like in the sample, but keeps the code.

Comment: For a line like `x = 5; // this is an inline comment` it deletes the whole line.  `sed 's/[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*\/\/.*//'` would only delete the comment portion.